# Periodic tasks in Django on Elastic Beanstalk (possibly with celery beat)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celerybeat

I'm trying to set up a daily task for my Django application on Elastic Beanstalk. There doesn't appear to be an accepted way to set this up, as celery beat is the go-to solution for periodic tasks in Django, but isn't great for load-balanced environments.

I've seen some solutions doing things like setting up celery beat with leader_only=True, to only run one instance, but that leaves a single point of failure. I've seen other solutions that allow many instances of celery beat and use locks to make sure only one task goes through, but wouldn't this still eventually fail completely unless the failed instances were restarted? Another suggestion I've seen is to have a separate instance for running celery beat, but this would still be a problem unless it had some way of restarting itself if it failed.

Are there any decent solutions to this problem? I would much rather not have to babysit a scheduler, as it would be pretty easy to not notice that my task was not being run until a while later.

Comment: What is the problem with running it on leader instance? If that instance fails health checks another instance will be promoted.

Comment: How would I go about making the health check fail if celerybeat fails?

Comment: If you're this concerned about points of failure and you're doing multi-instance load balancing, maybe it's time to consider setting up a dedicated logging/monitoring machine or buying into a service. Amazon offers one. I like Sentry.

Comment: were you able to get a good answer to your question? did you find that running a management command w/ cron on aws was preferred over setting up celery??

Answer (score 2):

If you're using redis as your broker, look into installing RedBeat as the celery beat scheduler: https://github.com/sibson/redbeat

This scheduler uses locking in redis to make sure only a single beat instance is running. With this you can enable beat on each node's worker process and remove the use of `leader_only=True`.

```
celery worker -B -S redbeat.RedBeatScheduler
```

Let's say you have Worker A with beat lock and Worker B. If Worker A dies, Worker B will attempt to acquire the beat lock after a [configurable](https://github.com/sibson/redbeat#redbeat_lock_timeout) amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) that runs with cron.

Using this method, you have your full Django ORM, all methods, etc. to work with. Wrapping your script in a try/except, you have the option to log failures in any way that you wish - email notifications, external logging systems like Sentry, straight to the DB, etc.

I user supervisord to run cron and it works well. It relies on time-tested tools that won't let you down.

Finally, using a database singleton to keep track of if a batch job has been run or is currently running in an environment where you have multiple instances of Django running load-balanced isn't bad practice, even if you feel a little icky about it. The DB is a very reliable means of telling you if the DB is being processed.

The one annoying thing about cron is that it doesn't import environment variables you may need for Django. I solved this with a simple Python script.

It writes the crontab on startup with needed environment variables etc. included. This example is for Ubuntu on EBS but should be relevant.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# run-cron.py
# sets environment variable crontab fragments and runs cron

import os
from subprocess import call
from master.settings import IS_AWS

# read django's needed environment variables and set them in the appropriate crontab fragment
eRDS_HOSTNAME = os.environ["RDS_HOSTNAME"]
eRDS_DB_NAME = os.environ["RDS_DB_NAME"]
eRDS_PASSWORD = os.environ["RDS_PASSWORD"]
eRDS_USERNAME = os.environ["RDS_USERNAME"]

try:
    eAWS_STAGING = os.environ["AWS_STAGING"]
except KeyError:
    eAWS_STAGING = None

try:
    eAWS_PRODUCTION = os.environ["AWS_PRODUCTION"]
except KeyError:
    eAWS_PRODUCTION = None

eRDS_PORT = os.environ["RDS_PORT"]

if IS_AWS:
    fto = '/etc/cron.d/stortrac-cron'
else:
    fto = 'test_cron_file'

with open(fto,'w+') as file:
    file.write('# Auto-generated cron tab that imports needed variables and runs a python script')

    file.write('\nRDS_HOSTNAME=')
    file.write(eRDS_HOSTNAME)
    file.write('\nRDS_DB_NAME=')
    file.write(eRDS_DB_NAME)
    file.write('\nRDS_PASSWORD=')
    file.write(eRDS_PASSWORD)
    file.write('\nRDS_USERNAME=')
    file.write(eRDS_USERNAME)
    file.write('\nRDS_PORT=')
    file.write(eRDS_PORT)
    if eAWS_STAGING is not None:
        file.write('\nAWS_STAGING=')
        file.write(eAWS_STAGING)
    if eAWS_PRODUCTION is not None:
        file.write('\nAWS_PRODUCTION=')
        file.write(eAWS_PRODUCTION)

    file.write('\n')

    # Process queue of gobs
    file.write('\n*/8 * * * * root python /code/app/manage.py queue --process-queue')
    # Every 5 minutes, double-check thing is done
    file.write('\n*/5 * * * * root python /code/app/manage.py thing --done')
    # Every 4 hours, do this
    file.write('\n8 */4 * * * root python /code/app/manage.py process_this')
    # etc.
    file.write('\n3 */4 * * * root python /ode/app/manage.py etc --silent')
    file.write('\n\n')

if IS_AWS:
    args = ["cron","-f"]
    call(args)
```

And in supervisord.conf:

```
[program:cron]
command = python /my/directory/runcron.py
autostart = true
autorestart = false
```